# PHP/MS SQL Server display sql server datetime

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

im trying to display date and time from **MSSQL Server** datetime table using PHP, the value from from SQL Server is datetime EX. `2012-08-20 06:23:28:214`. Now i want to display it the exact result but it php displays it like this EX. `Aug 20 2012 6:23AM`. I Have tried to use strtotime but the milliseconds does not display or rather display :`000`.

Any Help is so much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Judging by the yyyy-mm-dd date format, I am assuming you mean "MySQL server" when you say "SQL Server", which implies "MS SQL Server" -- an entirely different product.

Comment: sorry about that, that should be MS SQL SERVER..

Comment: @ytse_jam It should be MS SQL Server? I am slightly confused, if it isn't mysql, could you remove it from the title and tags - I would do it, but don't want to remove the wrong tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST('2012-08-20 06:23:28:214' as DateTime), 100) 
          AS [OutPut]

-- expected output
--     Aug 20 2012 6:23AM
```

from the example above, I used `CAST` in order to convert `string date` into the original `DateTime` datatype. But in the original query, *you can omit* the `CAST` function since you've mentioned that the column is already on the `DateTime` data type.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), columnDateTime, 100)
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6861a/7)

## [*How to Format Date and DateTime in MSSQL Server*](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: hi john, thank you so much. the select convert query did the trick. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's strtotime() to convert the sql date into unix time, then use date() to reformat it however you want. `=strtotime("2012-08-20 06:23:28.214")` works, so it's just a matter of using string manipulation to change that final colon into a decimal point.

Alternately, [this blog post](http://www.stev.org/post/2011/02/01/MS-SQL-Convert-to-unix-timestamp.aspx) has code that you can use to have MS SQL Server return the unix time directly. The key function is `SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '1970/01/01 00:00:00', @date)`.

If you are in fact using MySQL and not SQL Server, you can just use the function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to return the current unix time.

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) object has the input string type of `u` which represents microseconds (up to six of them).

[DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) does however use the same strings as the standard [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) But the following is taken from the docs about the `u` in outputting the data:

*Microseconds (added in PHP 5.2.2). Note that date() will always generate 000000 since it takes an integer parameter, whereas DateTime::format() does support microseconds.*

Comment: thanks for the answers, just to make it more clearer, im querying to MSSQL SERVER using PHP of course. the actual data from the MSSQL SERVER is like this  "2012-08-20 06:23:28:214", now if i echo it, the output is like this "Aug 20 2012 6:23AM". now what i want is to echo the actual data. as i said earlier i tried using strtotime but the milliseconds echoes :000.